# TIF not showing UTM coordinates in world file

Tags: lidar, imagery, utm, geotiff-tiff, world-file

I have a lot of tif files (ortho imagery that came with Lidar data). Each tile has a .tif and .tfw but the world files (.tfw) have line 5 and 6 as numbers that aren't what I would expect as I was expecting the files to be in UTM ZONE 10.

Is there anything I am missing that usually comes with Ortho Imagery / Lidar?
Or do I need to contact the supplier and ask them to re-export as a geo-referenced file. 
Or maybe this is just coordinates on a local site datum and that is it.

Below is an example of on the of the world files. The list number is the line number.

1. 0.200078983
2. 0
3. 0
4. -0.200078983
5. -1813.10469
6. 4172.72779

I guess the question is can you have ortho-rectified imagery on a local site datum? I thought maybe it would have to be real-world coordinates?

Comment: It does look like a local datum, too small for UTM but not small enough for DD. What happens when you separate the tif from the tfw files? It is possible that they are different. Is 20cm correct for you pixel size?

Comment: 20cm  is correct.I seperated the file and brought into Arcmap. Still small numbers and not in the correct space. I edited the original question to summarize my knowledge gap about local site datums and ortho imagery.

Comment: Ask for resupply, if you specified georeferenced imagery in your contract then something has gone wrong with the orthorectification... it should be a simple fix. If you can get the offsets from their current location to the correct location you can apply the Shift tool to move them to where they're supposed to be http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00170000007t000000

Comment: Ah I see. I'll do this, it's come second hand but i'll ask. Do I have to get the offsets - there is no way of calculating these?

Comment: You can have a good guess if you can find a point that is obvious and you know the *exact* location of, find the difference between the known coordinate and the raster coordinate and that should give you the values for X_Shift and Y_Shift - that is assuming the images don't need further rotation. If (most likely) all the images need to be moved by the same then they can be batched with a python script.. do you have any python experience?

Comment: Interesting. I know python. This is good stuff. There is actually a SID version and ECW that is a mosaic of all the TIFs. I guess I could apply the same logic and only have to do it once to the mosaicked image. I will have to see if I have any points that are known and surveyed. Do you have to consider earth curvature in the shift though?

Comment: It depends on how bad it looks. I don't think you can shift the ecw using that tool, instead use the ECW Header Editor in Apollo Web Utilities http://download.hexagongeospatial.com/?ProductName=7e6677bc-d93b-6e30-89b7-ff00003c6ea8. Provided the images have been orthorectified but to a local datum it should be safe to just shift them, it would only be if they were georeferenced to a local datum on a different projection that there could be problems.